# Git merge on sparse checkout workspace pulls all the other folder as well

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am facing a strange situation.

I did a sparse checkout ( Folder A ) from the repo for specific folder on my local branch. Suppose inside repo there are 3 folders in the root: A, B, and C.

repo:
/A
/B
/C

When I do a git merge from local branch to pull source code from other branch it pull's the content from all the folders (A, B, and C) to my local.
I was expecting only contents from A will be merged since sparse checkout is "ON".

Can you let me know how I can merge changes from other branch only contained in folder A.

Comment: The easier way I can think of is to `git stash` your changes... merge in the changes without committing using `git merge [branch] --no-commit --no-ff`. Then revert everything not in folder `A` and perform a `git stash pop` to bring in your local changes.

Comment: Thanks benhorgen for your update. can you tell me how do i do a partial revert of commits. suppose if i have more than 50+ commits. can you share the command for the same.

Comment: Using the example above: to reset folder `B` the command-line is: `git checkout B` followed by the same command for the `C` folder. Doing that command would reset the changes in those folders to their state of the `HEAD` of the branch.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, but only with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022): "[`git read-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/190f9bf62a17ca6f97dee3f3818450ab2927215b/Documentation/git-read-tree.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree))</sup> has been made to be aware of the **`sparse-index`** feature.

See [commit f27c170](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f27c170f645e6b8ed642c49c503964893ee26a4f), [commit ab81047](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab81047a6c5c4f98640f8a2f56e138367cfdada9), [commit 7497039](https://github.com/git/git/commit/749703924121b9eb2750b4313b2c769113c8b310), [commit 2c66a7c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c66a7c8cefa27ef56efbc76bdfe13696b9dac3a), [commit 14bf38c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14bf38cfcff0b68468444e85bc09c7d5007be34b), [commit cc89331](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc89331ddc92cd89012eaf7937d167b3e0beaecc), [commit 2c521b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c521b0e4900d8e7ff1f611ed956cfdd67f03eb0), [commit 287fd17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/287fd17e3a1daec2b0d0d8e26d2b2318511ec153) (01 Mar 2022) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 190f9bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/190f9bf62a17ca6f97dee3f3818450ab2927215b), 16 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`read-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab81047a6c5c4f98640f8a2f56e138367cfdada9): make two-way merge sparse-aware
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> Enable two-way merge with '[`git read-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ab81047a6c5c4f98640f8a2f56e138367cfdada9/Documentation/git-read-tree.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree))</sup> without expanding the sparse index.
> When in a sparse index, a two-way merge will trivially succeed as long as there are not changes to the same sparse directory in multiple trees (i.e., sparse directory-level "edit-edit" conflicts).
> If there are such conflicts, the merge will fail despite the possibility that individual files could merge cleanly.
>
> In order to resolve these "edit-edit" conflicts, "conflicted" sparse directories are - rather than rejected - merged by traversing their associated trees by OID.
> For each child of the sparse directory:
>
> 1. Files are merged as normal (see Documentation/git-read-tree.txt for
>    details).
> 2. Subdirectories are treated as sparse directories and merged in
>    '`twoway_merge`'. If there are no conflicts, they are merged according to
>    the rules in `Documentation/git-read-tree.txt`; otherwise, the subdirectory
>    is recursively traversed and merged.
>
> This process allows sparse directories to be individually merged at the necessary depth *without* expanding a full index.

---

Regarding [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68760316/git-merge-on-sparse-checkout-workspace-pulls-all-the-other-folder-as-well#comment121524229_68760316):

> The easier way I can think of is to git stash your changes.

Make sure to use Git 2.37 (Q3 2022): it teaches "[`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a9253cd45494b7b8aed8166529c5c451086f451/Documentation/git-stash.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> to work better with sparse index entries.

See [commit 0f329b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f329b9ae4f49d1f76cdd4cae518b2ae757e111e), [commit 874cf2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/874cf2a6044462ddba7162730557354a107c3a6d), [commit 491df5f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/491df5f679f0381f529b967df25476ab944406ab), [commit cfde4cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfde4cd6ffdca7670b62a292b144425767fb1759), [commit 3a58792](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a58792adece081ee84e9827c4d90daf759ceb76), [commit eae9370](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eae937059be0ae7b4a8e6bfbb985c8c079129419) (10 May 2022) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5a9253c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a9253cd45494b7b8aed8166529c5c451086f451), 20 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a58792adece081ee84e9827c4d90daf759ceb76): integrate with sparse index
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> Enable sparse index in '[`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a58792adece081ee84e9827c4d90daf759ceb76/Documentation/git-stash.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> by disabling '`command_requires_full_index`'.
>
> With sparse index enabled, some subcommands of 'stash' work without expanding the index, e.g., '`git stash`', '[`git stash list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a58792adece081ee84e9827c4d90daf759ceb76/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L70)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-listltlog-optionsgt))</sup>, '[`git stash drop`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a58792adece081ee84e9827c4d90daf759ceb76/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L135)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-drop-q%7C--quietltstashgt))</sup>, etc.
> Others ensure the index is expanded either directly (as in the case of '`git stash [pop|apply]`'', where the call to '`merge_recursive_generic()`' in '`do_apply_stash()`' triggers the expansion), or in a command called internally by stash (e.g., '[`git update-index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a58792adece081ee84e9827c4d90daf759ceb76/Documentation/git-update-index.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index))</sup> in '[`git stash -u`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a58792adece081ee84e9827c4d90daf759ceb76/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L163)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt--u))</sup>).
> So, in addition to enabling sparse index, add tests to 't1092' demonstrating which variants of '`git stash`' expand the index, and which do not.
>
> Finally, add the option to skip writing '`untracked.txt`' in '`ensure_not_expanded`', and use that option to successfully apply stashed untracked files without a conflict in '`untracked.txt`'.

And:

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/874cf2a6044462ddba7162730557354a107c3a6d): apply stash using '`merge_ort_nonrecursive()`'
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> Update 'stash' to use '`merge_ort_nonrecursive()`' to apply a stash to the current working tree.
> When '[`git stash apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/874cf2a6044462ddba7162730557354a107c3a6d/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L110)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-apply--index-q%7C--quietltstashgt))</sup> was converted from its shell script implementation to a builtin in [8a0fc8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a0fc8d19dff0c0ed09ce6656e353daf06c21892) ("`stash`: convert apply to builtin", 2019-02-25, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e36adf712251a19bd2ada0016764d340dfcf2ba0) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14c0f8d3ab6c36672189cd2dd217f4617d12ccba)), '`merge_recursive_generic()`' was used to merge a stash into the working tree as part of '[`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/874cf2a6044462ddba7162730557354a107c3a6d/Documentation/git-stash.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> (apply|pop)'.
> However, with the single merge base used in '`do_apply_stash()`', the commit wrapping done by '`merge_recursive_generic()`' is not only unnecessary, but misleading (the *real* merge base is labeled "constructed merge base").
> Therefore, a non-recursive merge of the working tree, stashed tree, and stash base tree is more appropriate.
>
> There are two options for a non-recursive merge-then-update-worktree function: '`merge_trees()`' and '`merge_ort_nonrecursive()`'.
> Use '`merge_ort_nonrecursive()`' to align with the default merge strategy used by '[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/874cf2a6044462ddba7162730557354a107c3a6d/Documentation/git-merge.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> ([6a5fb96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a5fb966720fffaae28bbd9408c55414c3b8c813) ("Change default merge backend from recursive to ort", 2021-08-04, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8778fa8b4f18a3930101825e5bcff62b5348e918) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c40894d2466d4e7fddc047a05116aa9d14712ee))) and, because `merge-ort` does not operate in-place on the index, avoid unnecessary index expansion.

---

Git 2.37.3 (Q3 2022) add fixes to sparse index compatibility work for "`reset`" and "`checkout`" commands.

See [commit b15207b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b15207b8cf1a1930fe5eb076c08c6ddc92d9282d), [commit 9553aa0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9553aa0f6c844085b3fbf05da5440dd7096dd764), [commit 56d8a27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56d8a27124b9bdfcaece7728649104c9121141a6), [commit 49ff3cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49ff3cb90fee9d0591b59a4c40ac2330163cab87) (08 Aug 2022) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 80ffc84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80ffc849bdd5ed111a2ec070856ef67e075572c6), 18 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49ff3cb90fee9d0591b59a4c40ac2330163cab87): fix nested sparse directory diff in sparse index
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> Add the '`recursive`' diff flag to the local changes reporting done by '[`git checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/49ff3cb90fee9d0591b59a4c40ac2330163cab87/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup> in '`show_local_changes()`'.
> **Without the flag enabled, unexpanded sparse directories will not be recursed into to report the diff of each file's contents, resulting in the reported local changes including "modified" sparse directories**.
>
> The same issue was found and fixed for '[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/49ff3cb90fee9d0591b59a4c40ac2330163cab87/Documentation/git-status.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> in [2c521b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c521b0e4900d8e7ff1f611ed956cfdd67f03eb0) ("`status`: fix nested sparse directory diff in sparse index", 2022-03-01, Git v2.36.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/190f9bf62a17ca6f97dee3f3818450ab2927215b) listed in [batch #12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74cc1aa55f30ed76424a0e7226ab519aa6265061))